# How can I gain access to the namespace for Html.HtmlHelper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I’m trying to create a helper class and started by adding namespace to web.config.

```
 <system.web.webPages.razor>
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace=" MyApplication"/>
         </namespaces>
</pages>
```

Then I created a folder called Helper and tried to create a method like this:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Web.WebPages.Html;


 namespace MyApplication.Helpers
 {
     public static class ViewBagHelpers
     {

    public static dynamic GetPageViewBag(this HtmlHelper html)
    {
        if (html == null || html.ViewContext == null) //this means that the page is root or parial view
        {
            return html.ViewBag;
        }

        ControllerBase controller = html.ViewContext.Controller;

        while (controller.ControllerContext.IsChildAction)  //traverse hierachy to get root controller
        {
            controller = controller.ControllerContext.ParentActionViewContext.Controller;
        }

        return controller.ViewBag;
    }



}
```

}

Then I get the error messages that System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper does not contain a definition for  html.ViewContext, html.ViewBag.

I've search similar questions and solutions but nothing works for me. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I believe instead this

```
using System.Web.WebPages.Html;
```

you actually wanted this:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
```

Comment: With both 

using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;


HtmlHelper and html.ViewBag; aren’t found.

With using System.Web.Mvc.Html alone, the others are not found.

It seems I need them both and something else to find HtmlHelper and html.ViewBag?

So I guess my new question is what do I need for HtmlHelper and html.ViewBag?

Comment: @CloudyKooper, having both usings aren't going to work since `HtmlHelper` is defined in both namespaces. And just `using System.Web.Mvc;` should be enough - `HtmlHelper` is defined there and it has `ViewBag` and `ViewContext`, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper%28v=vs.118%29.aspx). So unless you are trying to extend some other `HtmlHelper` - `System.Web.Mvc` is enough

Comment: Thanks, you're right.  However, I have Html.ViewData instead of Html.ViewBag.  Since I'm more familiar with ViewBag, is there something missing in my web.config file that would give me access to ViewBag?

Comment: @CloudyKooper, `ViewBag` should be accessed directly on the view: `@ViewBag.PropertyName`

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to follow an example I found here: https://gist.github.com/primaryobjects/8442193, which as return.html.  Wonder if it should be Html.ViewData which is found but not sure if it would work. I'll keep looking for examples that may work.  Thanks.

Comment: @CloudyKooper, I am afraid you should not follow it. This is not going to work: `if (html == null) { return html.ViewBag; }` even if HtmlHelper has `ViewBag` property